# Swipe from Right to Left to open Drawer

Tags: javascript, css

I have created a fork of this cool swipe drawer navigation: https://codepen.io/carl-victor-fontanos/pen/NQPLGW which works perfectly when swiping from Left to Right.

I am currently attempting to enable swiping from Right to Left, but I was only able to get it partially working. Here is what I've got so far: https://codepen.io/carl-victor-fontanos/pen/gVbdYq  -- in this pen you will notice that it now opens from Right to Left, but the problem is that the swipe is still in reverse which is not what I want. I have modified the CSS to get the position to appear in right instead of left, and in the Javascript side I have changed `translateX` from negative to positive value.

Hopefully someone can help me get this working, as I have been trying to solve this for hours.

Comment: 1 big note - on iOS swiping from the edge of the screen will cause the browser to go back/forward.

Answer (score 3):

The actual simple fix for the swipe direction is to set x = -x in the "move" function

```
    function move(x, e) {
      x = -x;
```

We could have a cleaner solution but this works.
Then I think you need to change the intent calculation because with just the x =-x change you need to swipe slowly until the edge to actually close the panel.
Hope this helps

(I just realised I just checked the closing not the opening).

Comment: Hey thanks again for your answer. The x = -x does solve the swiping direction issue, but still unable to get the swipe open of the drawer work. Are you still working on this?

Comment: I'll give it a look again tonight

Answer (score 0):

I believe you haven't changed the initial translation position

```
.drawer {
...
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
  -o-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
...
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zgxmBM

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, but it still swipes in reverse. The drawer should show when swiping from right to left, not the other way around.

Comment: oups sorry, I tought you were talking about the issue that at first load the panel opens from within the page instead of outside the page on the right side. I'm looking into the swipe issue.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to set the transform value to be hardcoded equal to the width of sidebar

```
.drawer {
...
  -webkit-transform: translateX(320px) or 100%;
  -moz-transform: translateX(320px) or 100%;
  -ms-transform: translateX(320px) or 100%;
  -o-transform: translateX(320px) or 100%;
  transform: translateX(320px) or 100%;
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately that didn't work.